# R: Using regmatches to extract certain characters

Tags: regex, r

I'm using regmatches to extract only capital letters from code, but "" replaces all lower case letters and numbers. Is there a way to just extract the capital letters and not have ""?

```
code <- c("clcopCow1zmstc0d87wnkig7OvdicpNuggvhryn92Gjuwczi8hqrfpRxs5Aj5dwpn0TanwoUwisdij7Lj8kpf03AT5Idr3coc0bt7yczjatOaootj55t3Nj3ne6c4Sfek.r1w1YwwojigOd6vrfUrbz2.2bkAnbhzgv4R9i05zEcrop.wAgnb.SqoU65fPa1otfb7wEm24k6t3sR9zqe5fy89n6Nd5t9kc4fE905gmc4Rgxo5nhDk!gr")

regmatches(code, gregexpr('[[:punct:]]*[[:upper:][:punct:]]*', code))
```

Comment: What output do you expect? `[[:punct:]]*[[:upper:][:punct:]]*` matches zero or more punctuation symbols followed with an uppercase letter (1 occurrence) followed with zero or more punctuation symbols - it cannot match more than 1 letter chunks.

Comment: Was hoping to only get the capital letters as it is an embedded message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub("[^A-Z]", "", code)
# [1] "CONGRATULATIONSYOUAREASUPERNERD"
```

Comment: than you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

`[^A-Z]` is good, but `[^[:upper:]]` is a little better, as it won't get screwed up in peculiar locales.

```
gsub("[^[:upper:]]", "", code)
```

For slightly better readability (but perhaps overkill for this example) you might want `stringr::str_extract`, but I'm not quite sure how to do this cleanly:

```
library(stringr)
str_c(str_extract_all(code,"[[:Lu:]]+")[[1]],collapse="")
```